# Best MATLAB toolbox that implements Support Vector Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, matlab

In this [Wikipedia article about SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Software) there are a number of links to different implementations of MATLAB toolboxes for Support Vector Machines. Could anyone suggest which of these is best in terms of speed, ease of use, etc.?

Comment: Wow, its been a long time since I've heard Support Vector Machine used in a public forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [libSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/). It is pretty fast and easy, and provides some useful tools, too. There are some examples of it in use [here](http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece539/matlab/). The other nice thing is that there are implementations in C++ and Java, too, so if you find yourself needing to develop outside of Matlab (to turn a prototype into something speedy, for example), you will have a familiar interface to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Without a doubt Cawley's is the best.

http://theoval.sys.uea.ac.uk/svm/toolbox/

Answer (score -1):

You can always use MathWorks implementation of SVM in the Bioinformatics Toolbox with the functions: **svmtrain** and **svmclassify**, which as usual have excellent documentation

Comment: He is asking for support vector regression, not binary classification.

Answer (score -4):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but if you want to speed up an M script look into the embedded matlab toolbox and MEX functions.  Basically, you can use these tools to compile your M scripts, I've done it and I get an order of magnitude performance gain minimum.  The people at the MW say you can get 100 fold improvement.